# Using "Grid" instead of "UserControl" on ModernUI - WPF

Tags: wpf, grid, modern-ui

On ModernUI, we have "ModernTab" isntead of using "TabControl"
But How could I show "" inside of each tabs, instead of using userControl.
My mean I looking to add "Grid" inside of each Tab

Code on ModernUI:

```
<mui:ModernTab SelectedSource="/Content/ControlsStylesButton.xaml" Layout="List">
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Button" Source="/Content/ControlsStylesButton.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="DataGrid" Source="/Content/ControlsStylesDataGrid.xaml" />
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
```

My code on Normal WPF Window:

```
<TabControl    SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
<TabItem  Name="tiProfileEdit"  Header="profile"  >
<Grid>
//UI of this tab instead of using usercontrol
</Grid>
</TabItem>
<TabItem  Name="tiDataGrid"  Header="DataGrid"  >
<Grid>
//UI of this tab instead of using usercontrol
</Grid>
</TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `<Grid>` as the root element of the `UserControl`.

A `Link` is not a `ContentControl` and doesn't have any concept of direct content. It only has a `Source` property so it is nothing like a built-in `TabItem`.